# Facebook app request data loss, when app not installed and redirect to google market

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook app request data loss, when app not installed and redirect to google market. If app already installed then, request notification open the app and no data loss.

How to and where, we can save app request in case of fb notification redirection to market?